# AngularJS: Single route app architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to determine how to take advantage of Angular's toolset for a problem I'm trying to solve.

My application will be a single page application, but it will also only have one route. There is no other "state" as in URL state at all. As far as I can tell, you can take advantage of controllers and views in a 1:1 relationship with a route.

**What I would like is to have Controller+View combinations for components on the page. (A component could be a widget, modal window, etc.).**

Is there any way to leverage Angular in this situation?

Note: I have seen https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, but this still relies heavily on creating "states" of the application and tying it to a URL.

Comment: What you're describing is a 'directive'. An angular directive has a view, a controller, and even its own scope (depending on how its set up) - it can be considered a self-contained widget.  I don't recommend using  routes for widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include HTML partials, you can use the `ng-include` directive. This can be coupled with the `ng-controller` directive in a few different ways:

You can nest an element with `ng-include` inside an `ng-controller`:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-include="'view.html'"></div>
</div>
```

You can include an `ng-controller` directive inside an included partial:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ng-include="'view.html'"></div>

<!-- view.html -->
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <p>{{ helloworld }}</p>
</div>
```

You can also combine `ng-include` and `ng-controller` directives on the same element:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-include="'view.html'"></div>
```

Please note that in each of the examples above, the string literal in the `ng-include` directive is wrapped in single quotes - this is because the directive expects an expression.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may need to utilize one or more of these techniques. I also expect you'll need to work heavily with directives (for example, you can use the [UI Bootstrap modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)), which can have their own controller as well.

I set up a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bCb6gdkrIJw4OUw8NuSk?p=preview) with a couple working examples of the `ng-include` options listed above, including swapping the included template dynamically.

I can't speak to the feasibility of actually building a production application like this, but it appears to be possible, at least on first glance.